# iOS 8 - Time Format As A Decimal

Tags: ios, time, ios8, xcode6, decimal

For an project I am doing regarding iOS Programming, I need to convert the current 24-hour time to decimals, then store the string in a label. Below are some examples of how I need the time to be output:

- 3:24 PM should be 15.4 (since 24 is 40% of 60)
- 11:02 AM should be 11.03
- 7:56 PM should be 19.93

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to get the time in 24 hour. So this covers your last two points.

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
NSLog(@"%@", resultString);
```

Now as to the first question, what you need to do is to store the minutes in a separate variable and then do a simple percentage to find out the decimal number and then create a new time string, like so:

```
NSArray *dateArray = [resultString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSString *hour = [dateArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *minute = [dateArray objectAtIndex:1];

int percentage = [minute intValue];
percentage = ((percentage / 60) * 100);

NSString *newTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%d", hour, percentage];

NSLog(@"New time is: %@", newTime);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: `percentage / 60 * 100` and then still display it after the dot? Why not simply `hour + (percentage / 60)`?

Comment: @Eimantas read the question please. In the question it says 15.4. The 15 and the 4 being separated by a dot. jjj wants a string with the hour and then a dot and then the percentage.

Comment: `24 / 60 == 0.4`. Thus, `15 + 0.4 == 15.4`. So you can make `int hour = [dateArray[0] intValue]; int minute = [dateArray[1] intValue];`, do the percentage calculation and add hour to minute.

Comment: @eimantas I used the basics of Dan's code, but I did use your suggestion too; that helped a lot! :)